# Material UI and React Issue: module not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

Okay, so I have uninstalled and reinstalled material-ui core and icons using npm. I have tried using next and latest.
I have also tried using RaisedButton instead of just Button.
I am using docker, and I have rebuilt this project a few times to make sure it wasn't a server/caching issue.
However, I am still getting
`"Module  not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Button in '/app/src'`

When I look in my node modules however, the button module is there.
[image: screenshot of default code example for material-ui]

[image]

Comment: Which bundler are you using? Have you changed your webpack config?

Comment: The error states that it cannot find the module in ```app/source```. I think it should be looking in the ```node_modules``` folder instead. I'm not sure why that is though

Comment: I am using the default bundler that comes with create-react-app so I think that's webpack

Comment: thanks @szczocik I didn't even really connect that, I'll see if I can figure out why